# include UNIX utility 'file' in C program

Tags: c, linux, mime-types

I'm writing a program in C, and I need to known the mime-type of a file.

I have yet searched with Google, and I found that [I must include the 'file' UNIX utility in my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423626/get-mime-type-from-filename-in-c).

The source code of `file` need `configure` and `make`. How I can include this in my project? Do I have to crop a part of the source code into a new `file.c` and `file.h`?

Comment: "I need to know the mime-type of a file" -> Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137732/how-to-generate-the-http-content-type-header-in-c/9137758, which I answered as http://stackoverflow.com/a/9137758/960195

Comment: You need more than the binary. File uses /etc/magic, which contains "fingerprints" for the various file types. Best/simplest way is simply to use popen() or system().

Comment: Using `popen` or `system` is (always) a very bad idea. There's `libmagic`, or if you want to invoke `file(1)`, you should use `posix_spawn`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you want to guess the MIME type based on the extension, or do something like `file` and examine the headers?

To get functionality similar to `file`, you don't need to include `file` in your project. Instead, you'll want to use libmagic which `file` is based on. Unfortunately I'm not aware of a good source of documentation for this, but it's pretty straightforward.

```
magic_t magic = magic_open(MAGIC_MIME_TYPE);
magic_load(magic, NULL);
char *mime_type = magic_file(magic, "/path/to/file");
magic_close(magic);
```

Comment: Other example usage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105816/trying-to-use-include-compile-3rd-party-library-libmagic-c-c-filetype-detect

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for yours answers and comments.

I solved with this:

```
const char *w_get_mime(const char *arg, const char *file, int line_no)
{

    const char *magic_full;
    magic_t magic_cookie;

    if(arg == NULL)
        w_report_error("called with NULL argument.",file,line_no,__func__,0,1,error);
    else if ((magic_cookie = magic_open(MAGIC_MIME) ) == NULL) 
        report_error("unable to initialize magic library.",0,1,error);
    else if (magic_load(magic_cookie, NULL) != 0) 
    {
        magic_close(magic_cookie);
        snprintf(globals.err_buff,MAX_BUFF,"cannot load magic database - %s .",magic_error(magic_cookie));
        report_error(globals.err_buff,0,1,error);
    }
    magic_full = magic_file(magic_cookie, arg);
    magic_close(magic_cookie);
    return magic_full;
}
```

thanks a lot! :)